# The increment integer won't increase by 2 in the for loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, integer, increment

This is my code.

```
for (int i = 0; i<shots.size(); i=i+2){ //I would expect "i" to increase by 2 for every loop.
            i = i%4; //On this line, there is ALWAYS that i==2
            switch (i){
            case 0: boards[1].getTile(shots.get(i),shots.get(i+1)).shoot();
                break;
            case 2: boards[0].getTile(shots.get(i),shots.get(i+1)).shoot();
                break;
            }
            if (gameOver()){
                break;
            }
        }
```

But when I run the debugger, I see that "i" is reset to 0 every time I hit the loop initializer, and then "i" is set to "2" on the first line inside the loop. I want this to behave like a regular for loop, only that I want "i" to increase by 2 instead of 1 for each iteration. Is there any way I can do that?

Thanks for all help!

Comment: Why `i = i%4;`?  That will make `i` a value bewteen 0-3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is your problem

```
 i = i%4;
```

Lets look at what `i` does:

```
i = 0 is 0
i = i % 4 is the remainder of 0 / 4 which is 0
i = i + 2 is 2
i = i % 4 is the remainder of 2 / 4 which is 2
i = i + 2 is 4
i = i % 4 is the remainder of 4 / 4 which is 0
```

Thus unless `shots.size()` is less than 2 you loop forever unless `gameOver()` becomes true and you break out of the loop.  You can do as @Eran suggests
and create a new int `j` to be the mod of `i` or (since you aren't using `j` anywhere else) just do this:

```
switch (i%4)
```

Comment: Ahahaha! God, how did I miss that. I'll count to 100 before my next post here.

Comment: Hey if coding was easy it wouldn't be as much fun : )

Comment: Still the nicest reply I've ever seen in a SO comment.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need two variables :

```
    for (int i = 0; i<shots.size(); i=i+2){
        int j = i%4; // j will always be either 0 or 2, so the switch statement
                     // will toggle between the two cases
        switch (j){
        case 0: boards[1].getTile(shots.get(i),shots.get(i+1)).shoot();
            break;
        case 2: boards[0].getTile(shots.get(i),shots.get(i+1)).shoot();
            break;
        }
        if (gameOver()){
            break;
        }
    }
```

For this to work, `shots.size()` must be even. If it's odd `shots.get(i+1)` will eventually throw an exception.